# What is the RESTful way to return a JSON + binary file in an API

Tags: json, rest, get, hateoas, http-delete

I have to implement a REST endpoint that receives start and end dates (among other arguments). It does some computations to generate a result that is a kind of forecast according to the server state at invocation epoch and the input data (imagine a weather forecast for next few days).
Since the endpoint does not alter the system state, I plan to use GET method and return a JSON.

The issue is that the output includes also an image file (a plot). So my idea is to create a unique id for the file and include an URI in the JSON response to be consumed later (I think this is the way suggested by HATEOAS principle).

My question is, since this image file is a resource that is valid only as part of the response to a single invocation to the original endpoint, I would need a way to delete it once it was consumed.

Would it be RESTful to deleting it after serving it via a GET?

or expose it only via a DELETE?

or not delete it on consumption and keep it for some time? (purge should be performed anyway since I can't ensure the client consumes the file).

I would appreciate your ideas.

Comment: How large is the payload? You _could_ base64 encode the binary and use a JSON String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be RESTful to deleting it after serving it via a GET?

Yes.

> or expose it only via a DELETE?

Yes.

> or not delete it on consumption and keep it for some time?

Yes.

The last of these options (caching) is a decent fit for REST in HTTP, since we have meta-data that we can use to communicate to general purpose components that a given representation has a finite lifetime.

So this reference of the report (which includes the link to the plot) could be accompanied by an [Expires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3) header that informs the client that the representation of the report has an expected shelf life.

You might, therefore, plan to garbage collect the image resource after 10 minutes, and if the client hasn't fetched it before then - poof, [gone](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9).

The reason that you might want to keep the image around after you send the response to the GET: [the network is unreliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing), and the GET message may never reach its destination.  Having things in cache saves you the compute of trying to recalculate the image.

If you want confirmation that the client did receive the data, then you must introduce another message to the protocol, for the client to inform *you* that the image has been downloaded successfully.

It's reasonable to combine these strategies: schedule yourself to evict the image from the cache in some fixed amount of time, but also evict the image immediately if the consumer acknowledges receipt.

But REST doesn't make any promises about liveness - you could send a response with a link to the image, but 404 Not Found every attempt to GET it, and that's fine (not *useful*, of course, but fine).  REST doesn't promise that resources have stable representations, or that the resource is somehow eternal.

REST gives us standards for how we request things, and how responses should be interpreted, but we get a lot of freedom in choosing which response is appropriate for any given request.

Comment: Technically, HTTP gives us those standards; REST really just says that there should be those standards ("self descriptive messages").

Answer (score 1):

It's a tricky one. Typically `GET` requests should be repeatable as an import HTTP feature, in case the original failed. Some people might rely on it.

It could also be construed as a 'non-safe' operation, `GET` resulting in what is effectively a `DELETE`.

I would be inclined to expire the image after X seconds/minutes instead, perhaps also supporting `DELETE` at that endpoint if the client got the result and wants to clean up early.

Answer (score 0):

You could offer a download link in the JSON response to that binary resource that also contains the parameters that are required to generate that resource. Then you can decide yourself when to clean that file up (managing disk space) or cache it - and you can always regenerate it because you still have the parameters. I assume here that the generation doesn't take significant time.